# Set specific Date/Time on Angular Date/Time Picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, datetimepicker

I am attempting to set a predefined Date and Time for the Angular Bootstrap Date Picker. I am also using the rather lovely Date Time extension by Gillardo found here: https://github.com/Gillardo/bootstrap-ui-datetime-picker

The back story: I have had a form that I am able to pick a date and time and save it to a DB. I now have a new form that is meant to read in that value, pre-populate the 'update' form, and then write the new value back to the DB when it is modified.

Initially a date is set with new Date(); which works perfectly for the first form. However I don't understand how to pre-populate the update form datetime picker field to reflect the previously chosen date.

I have had a play around with init-date from the docs. But no luck so far :(

Here's some code of where I am at right now.

HTML:

```
<p class="input-group" data-field-name={{field.name}}>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" datetime-picker="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm" ng-model="ctrl.dates.StartDate" is-open="ctrl.open.StartDate" data-set-date-time />
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="ctrl.openCalendar($event, 'StartDate')">
            <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
        </button>
    </span>
</p>
<input class="form-control-static form-field" id={{field.name}} value={{ctrl.dates.StartDate}} />
```

Angular Directive:

```
app.directive ('setDateTime', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, ngModelCtrl) {
            $timeout(function() {
                console.log(element.val());
                console.log(ngModelCtrl);
            })
        }
    }
});
```

I hope that makes sense. Please let me know if you need anything else. I really appreciate any help you can give me.

Many thanks,

Dan

Comment: could you create a plnkr plz ?

Comment: The `ng-model` of the date picker input field holds a `Date` type object that corresponds to the selected date. So, if you want to pre-populate the date picker field with a given date, you've to assign a `Date` type object to it's `ng-model`. Try to construct a `Date` type object back from your saved date and assign it to `ng-model` of the date picker

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. After tearing my hair out trying to get the functionality working to demonstrate on Plunker, I went away and had another think about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help guys. After tearing my hair out trying to get the functionality working to demonstrate on Plunker from @macrog suggestion, I went away and had another think about it.

I finally got it working by using a `$watch` to monitor the data coming in. Then assigning a new dynamically called value to the scope.

```
scope.$watch('formData', function(formData) {
    if(formData) {  
        scope.ctrl.dates.StartDate = formData.startDateTime;
    }
});
```

This fixed the issue. Yay!